# Having trouble joining multiple tables. Expected results are very close to actual results

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that I am looking to join. I have a query that gives me almost exactly what I am looking for, but it is slightly off of what I expect. I am just looking for some help fleshing out what is going wrong.

My 3 tables (Keep in mind this example will be a simplified version of the tables):

usergroups

users

groupmemebers

usercosts

The query I am trying to build will display the User, the count of services they have, and the total cost to the user. 
My expected output is:

```
User Group  | User Count | Cost
Bob's Group |     12     | 2125.98
```

The query I have come up with is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usergroups.groupname, COUNT(DISTINCT users.userid), SUM(usercosts.billed) 
FROM usergroups
LEFT JOIN users ON usergroups.userid = users.userid
LEFT JOIN groupmemebers ON usergroups.username = groupmemebers.username
LEFT JOIN usercosts ON usergroups. username = usercosts.username
WHERE groupmemebers.groupowner = 'Bob’s'
AND usergroups.username = 'Bob's Group'
```

The output that I get is:

```
User Group  | User Count | Cost
Bob's Group |      12    | 25511.76
```

The 25511.76 is my expected cost multiplied by the service count. So, I am close, but something is missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did You try inner joins instead of left joins?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the source data. So we can reproduce the results and adjust your query to return your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses. I ended up just doing 2 separate joins and joining those results. It might not be the prettiest, but it works.

I'll post the query here and if someone has an idea on how to optimize it feel free to comment.

```
SELECT t1.group, t1.billable, t2.users FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT usergroups.groupname AS group, SUM(usercosts.billed) AS billable FROM usergroups
LEFT JOIN groupmemebers ON usergroups.username = groupmemebers.username
LEFT JOIN usercosts ON usergroups. username = usercosts.username
WHERE usergroups.username = 'Bob\'s Group') t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT usergroups.groupname AS group, COUNT(DISTINCT users.userid)) AS users FROM usergroups
LEFT JOIN users ON usergroups.userid = users.userid
LEFT JOIN groupmemebers ON usergroups.username = groupmemebers.username
WHERE usergroups.username = 'Bob\'s Group') t2
ON (t1.group = t2.group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your joins are creating duplicates and the distinct after your select is applied after the aggregates.

Think of it as mysql first doing the select * of you query

```
SELECT * FROM usergroups
LEFT JOIN users ON usergroups.userid = users.userid
LEFT JOIN groupmemebers ON usergroups.username = groupmemebers.username
LEFT JOIN usercosts ON usergroups. username = usercosts.username
WHERE groupmemebers.groupowner = 'Bob’s'
AND usergroups.username = 'Bob's Group'
```

Then does the sum/count aggregates from that result